# Media query for screen larger than 600px

Tags: css, media-queries

I wrote a class with CSS properties and I want it in the way that the screen at my breaking point which I've decided then media query work how I can use the for example:

When the screen is larger than 600px then it works and
if the screen is less than the breaking point then this media query works.

```css
.test {
  width: 30% !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .test {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

That is not working. Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: can you add your html to the question please so that we have more context

Comment: I tried to rewrite the question but it is still not clear.

Comment: This question needs proof-reading by the author and editing. All I can workout is that you say the code works when the screen is larger than or less than 600px (so does not work if exactly 600px). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you provided is valid.

If you are not seeing the expected result, the following things may be happening:

1. There is no element in your HTML which has a `class` of `test`. — If you run `document.querySelectorAll('.test')` in the console and you are not getting any results, then there are no elements which match the CSS selector of `.test`.
2. The CSS is actually not being loaded. Maybe you are not putting your styles inside a `<style>` tag, or you are not correctly loading the stylesheet with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/styles.css"/>`?  — Your browser’s developer tools should show your stylesheet being loaded in the *Networks* panel. Alternatively, styles should be present on the page, within a `<style>` tag.
3. The CSS rules are being overwritten. Are there are any styles which are styling the `.test` element(s) after the above CSS rules are applied? — Your browser’s developer tools can show if styles are being applied or not.

Sharing your HTML will make it easier for people to help you.